# BASH: move files according to dirname

Tags: bash, for-loop

I would like to move a number of processed files from their raw directory to a new directory. Each directory name corresponds, but only by two numbers; the rest of the dir names are different. How can I define a pattern within a for-loop to easily find and move these files to and from their corresponding dirs?

More details: 
I have two sets of 90 directories. The first set contains raw files, and the second is where I’d like to move corresponding gzipped files. The problem is that the first and second sets of directories only share one part of their name: the first is `ABC_1##`; the second is `##YY00ZZ` (ex: raw dir `ABC_123` corresponds to new dir `23yy00zz`. There is a complicated but necessary reason that they have to follow this format). The gzipped files are all given the same name (let’s call it FILE.gz), but crucially must go from raw dir 23 to new dir 23…

This is what I have tried, and it is not working for me (using cp instead of mv so as to avoid messing up too much):

```
for dir in $(ls -d ~/path/to/raw/ABC_1{01..90}/EACH_RAW_DIR); do
    dir2=$(ls -d ~/path/to/new/{01..90}yy00zz/EACH_NEW_DIR)
    echo $dir
    echo $dir2
    cp -r $dir/FILE.gz $dir2/.
done
```

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Are "EACH_RAW_DIR" and "EACH_NEW_DIR" actual directories? Can you give an example of a full `mv` command that'd be needed to move one of the files?

Answer (score 1):

shell expansion won't expand {01..90} with padded zeros. It would expand it as 1,2,3,...,11,12,...,90. Better to do it in two steps: 1) first `ABC_10{1..9}` 2) `ABC_1{10..90}`

or you can use `seq -w 90`

Once you have taken care of that, you only need to copy like this:

```
for i in "$(seq -w 90)"; do
      cp ~/path_to_raw_dir/ABC_1"$i"/file.gz ~/path_to_new_dir/"$i"yy00zz/file.gz
done
```

Comment: In `bash` 4 or later,  `{01..90}` will expand to `00, 01, 02, ..., 90`.

Comment: Also, quoting `"$(seq -w 90)"` will loop just once over a very long argument (all the numbers)!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a range of `{101..190}` and chop off the first digit as needed:

```
for i in {101..190}; do
      cp ~/path_to_raw_dir/ABC_$i/file.gz ~/path_to_new_dir/${i:1}yy00zz/file.gz
done
```